# Find the $P[X_1 \leq X_2]$ given that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are exponential random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$X_1$ and $X_2$ are 2 independent exponential random variables of parameters of 1 and 2 respectively. If so then

$P[X_1 \leq X_2]=?$

This is what i have to find! What i did was:

If i set $X_1=t \to P[t\leq X_2]$ then

$P[X_1 \leq X_2]=\int_0 ^\infty P[X_2\geq t] f_{x_1}(t)dt]=$

$\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda_2t}\lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 t}dt$

where $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_2=2$ and the rest is just computations!
WHat i wanted to know was:

First of all Is the line of thinking correct?

And Second: Can i apply this way of solving things if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are lets say Bernoulli, Binomial, Geometric, Poisson distributions and for the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I see what you are doing and that works.

Alternatively, joint pdf $f(X_1, X_2) = f(X_1) f(X_2)$ as $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.

$X_1 \leq X_2 \implies 0 \leq X_1 \leq X_2, 0 \leq X_2 \leq \infty$

So integral becomes,

$\displaystyle \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{x_2} e^{-(\lambda_1 x_1 + \lambda_2 x_2)} \ dx_1 \ dx_2 $

Here we have $\lambda_1 = 1, \lambda_2 = 2$ so,

$P(X_1 \leq X_2) = \displaystyle 2 \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{x_2} e^{-(x_1 + 2 x_2)} \ dx_1 \ dx_2 $

Comment: I also knew of this method but as i said in the question above the method i used above can it be used for other types of distributions?

Comment: Yes in general, if they are both independent random variables, you should be able to. Also note that the constraint $X_1 \leq X_2$ is more straightforward but constraints may not be this straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a drawing of the problem you see that the integration area is the infinite triangle over $X=Y$ thus

$$P(X<Y)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}\left[  \int_x^{\infty}2e^{-2y}dy \right]dx=\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: Thanks! I knew of this method as well but There is also something else i would like to ask. Is it possible to use the method above for different types of distributions?